# Insert data from a form to mysql database using spring boot,bootstrap and angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

[image]I am using a boostrap template : SB Admin2 where i have in the folder pages a form with 2 inputs : databseName and numberColumns .I want to insert the values of inputs in a table in my database which name is DB and columns are : `(id_database,database_name,columns_number)`

Here's my controller

```
package demo.controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import demo.connection.SingletonConnection;
import demo.dao.IDatabase;
import demo.dao.IEntities;
import demo.entities.DB;

@Controller
public class DatabaseController implements ErrorController{
    private static final String PATH = "/error";
    protected Connection conn;
     @Autowired
     private IDatabase db;
     @Autowired 
     private IEntities entities;

    // En cas d'érreur
        @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
        public String error() {
            return "Error";
        }
        @Override
        public String getErrorPath() {
            return PATH;
        }



     @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String test(Model model){
            try {

            DB db=new DB();

            model.addAttribute("db",new DB());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "forms";
     }
     @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)

     public String saveDB(@ModelAttribute DB db,Model modelDB )
     {
         try {
            modelDB.addAttribute("db",db);
      this.conn=SingletonConnection.getConnection();
        Statement ps1 = conn.createStatement();
        ps1.execute("INSERT INTO DB (database_name,columns_number) "+" VALUES"+"("+db.getDatabase_name()+","+db.getColumns_number());
        ps1.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "blank";

     }
}


Here's the form 



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
        <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-header -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <em>Yesterday</em>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <em>Yesterday</em>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <em>Yesterday</em>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                    <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                    <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                    <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                </ul>
                <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

                <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                            <li class="sidebar-search">
                                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /input-group -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
            </nav>

            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Create database</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Basic Form Elements
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <form role="form">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Database_name</label>
                                                <input class="form-control">
                                                <p class="help-block">the name of database required</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Columns_number</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a number">
                                            </div>

                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
        <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
        <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Now when i type in the browser :localhost:8080/test  i have a blank bage

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in your log file?

Comment: No i don't have any error or exception

Comment: Does your webapp run under the default path ("/")?

Comment: do you mean if i type localhost:8080/  does the application run? if it's the case it also gives me a blank page

Comment: So does the application run at all? And if under which path? Please show us the log of the application start in which the DatabaseController is supposed to run. Or did you not even start the app?

Comment: I update the post where i show the log, for the path , i run the application with http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: Since you posted a ******* screen shot and not the actual text, that doesn't help a lot, **but**: As you can see, there are some **ERROR**s in the log: `unsuccessful: alter table va` [...] - Wild guess: investigate these errors, fix  them and your webapp might work better. ;) If you have to, drop these tables if they cannot be altered and if the contents don't matter.